# VB programmers. I have a problemas with form navigation

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a few forms in my program and I obviously have navigation as well. NEXT and BACK buttons. I have the NEXT buttons coded like so:

```
Private Sub NextButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles NextButton.Click
    ' Closes current screen and opens the next

    Me.Visible = False
    Form4.ShowDialog()
End Sub
```

And the BACK buttons like so:

```
Private Sub BackButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BackButton.Click
    ' Closes current screen and opens the previous screen
    Me.Visible = False
    Form2.ShowDialog()
End Sub
```

As you can tell this is from Form3.

So. I go forward fine, but as soon as I hit back my program doesnt want to run.

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: VB.NET and VBA are **NOT** the same thing.  Please tag responsibly :)

Comment: You really took the time to post just to say that? WOW. Are you bored?

Comment: Nope, not bored at all.  But tagging your posts correctly will increase the chances of you getting help with your question.  Throwing in a bunch of unrelated tags could make you look desperate :)

Comment: I'm new at vb. I thought thats what vb is. whats vba?

Comment: VBA = Visual Basic for Applications.  It's used extensively in Microsoft Office - for example, Excel macros.

Comment: Tim, what makes you think this is VBA? VBA does not use a Handles clause, but VB.net does.

Comment: @rontornambe - OP had originally tagged the question with both VB.NET and VBA.  I removed the VBA tag.  Guess I should have said that in the comment :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When showing a form using 'ShowDialog' in VB, you have to evaluate the response and dismiss the form. Just setting Visible to false isn't enough.

See code here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2

You may just want to show the form, not showDialog it, and there's samples here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.show.aspx

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Laurence. I Show() them instead of ShowDialog() them and they work ok. I also changed the Visibility to Me.Hide(). Some of them are latent when they go back but they do at least. I am sure there is a better way to do this but for beginers I'm sure they want me to do the simple way. Thanks anyway

Comment: Awesome...please flag this as the answer in that case :)

Answer (score 1):

If you must use OpenDialog, here's an example on how this can be accomplished:

Firstly a reference to Form1 needs to be set in the load event. The reference must first be created in Form2 (see below):

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Form2.f1 = Me
    End Sub

Private Sub Next_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ButNext.Click
    Me.Visible = False
    Form2.ShowDialog()
End Sub
```

In Form2, create a Form1 public variable that is set in the load event of Form1. In the Previous button handler, set the reference to Form1's visible property to True instead of calling ShowDialog.

```
Public Class Form2
    Public Property f1 As Form1 ' you can also create a variable instead of a property

    Private Sub Previous_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ButPrev.Click
        f1.Visible = True
        Me.Visible = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub ButNext_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ButNext.Click
        Me.Visible = False
        Form3.ShowDialog()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        ' repeat process for Form3
        Form3.f2 = Me
    End Sub
End Class
```

Repeat this process for all dialog forms in your application.